Calling student method from parent class definition
I'm making an LCD menu and having trouble with the lcdmenu (main menu) and submenu interaction.
class submenu;

class lcdmenu
{
protected:
    command **commandlist;
    submenu **submenulist;
    ...   

public:
    void setchildren(command **comlist, submenu **sublist, int comn, int subn);
    void render();
    ...

};

void lcdmenu::render(){
    lcd_clear();
    for (int line = 0; line < MAX_LINES; line ++){
        int index = menutop + line;
        ...

        if (index < numcommands){
            lcd_string(commandlist[index]->get_text());
            lcd_string(submenulist[index]->get_text()); 
        }

class submenu : public lcdmenu {
public:
    lcdmenu *parent;
    submenu(lcdmenu *par, const char* text);

    const char* get_text(){
        return text;
    }
};

submenu::submenu(lcdmenu *par, const char* text_):text(text_), parent(par)
{
}

I am passing a list of submenu instances into the lcdmenu.submenulist variable, and I want lcdmenu::render() to call  lcd_string(submenulist[index]->get_text()); but I can not use submenu.get_text when that method has not been defined yet.
Is there a way to format my file so I can use both the fully defined lcdmenu class and submenu classes within each other?

WHat do you mean by "student method"? Did you mean "subclass method"?

If you have public inheritance without virtual functions, you are probably doing something wrong.

You can't use a class method before it has been declared.
Using a forward declaration is the correct way to address circular references between classes. So what you are doing for the lcdmenu::submenulist member (and presumably the same for the lcdmenu::commandlist member) is perfectly fine for the purpose of declaring the lcdmenu class.
But, the forward declaration does not help the implementation of the lcdmenu::render() method.  It needs the full declaration of the submenu class in order to access its members, such as the submenu::get_text() method (and the same with the command class).
So, you need to split up your declarations and implementations into separate .h and .cpp files to help facilitate this task, eg:
lcdmenu.h
#ifndef lcdmenu_H
#define lcdmenu_H

class command;
class submenu;

class lcdmenu
{
protected:
    command **commandlist;
    submenu **submenulist;
    ...   

public:
    void setchildren(command **comlist, submenu **sublist, int comn, int subn);
    void render();
    ...
};

#endif

lcdmenu.cpp
#include "lcdmenu.h"
#include "submenu.h"
#include "command.h"
...

void lcdmenu::render(){
    lcd_clear();
    for (int line = 0; line < MAX_LINES; line ++){
        int index = menutop + line;
        ...

        if (index < numcommands){
            lcd_string(commandlist[index]->get_text());
            lcd_string(submenulist[index]->get_text()); 
        }

submenu.h
#ifndef submenu_H
#define submenu_H

#include "lcdmenu.h"

class submenu : public lcdmenu {
public:
    lcdmenu *parent;
    submenu(lcdmenu *par, const char* text);

    const char* get_text();
};

#endif

submenu.cpp
#include "submenu.h"

submenu::submenu(lcdmenu *par, const char* text_):text(text_), parent(par)
{
}

const char* submenu::get_text(){
    return text;
}

command.h
#ifndef command_H
#define command_H

...

class command ... {
public:
    ...
    const char* get_text();
};

#endif

command.cpp
#include "command.h"

...

const char* command::get_text(){
    return ...;
}

Now, when you compile lcdmenu.cpp, the compiler will see the following code after preprocessor substitutions:
class command;
class submenu;

class lcdmenu
{
protected:
    command **commandlist;
    submenu **submenulist;
    ...   

public:
    void setchildren(command **comlist, submenu **sublist, int comn, int subn);
    void render();
    ...
};

class submenu : public lcdmenu {
public:
    lcdmenu *parent;
    submenu(lcdmenu *par, const char* text);

    const char* get_text();
};

...
class command ... {
public:
    ...
    const char* get_text();
};

...

void lcdmenu::render(){
    lcd_clear();
    for (int line = 0; line < MAX_LINES; line ++){
        int index = menutop + line;
        ...

        if (index < numcommands){
            lcd_string(commandlist[index]->get_text());
            lcd_string(submenulist[index]->get_text()); 
        }

And when you compile submenu.cpp, the compiler will see the following code after preprocessor substitutions:
class command;
class submenu;

class lcdmenu
{
protected:
    command **commandlist;
    submenu **submenulist;
    ...   

public:
    void setchildren(command **comlist, submenu **sublist, int comn, int subn);
    void render();
    ...
};

class submenu : public lcdmenu {
public:
    lcdmenu *parent;
    submenu(lcdmenu *par, const char* text);

    const char* get_text();
};

submenu::submenu(lcdmenu *par, const char* text_):text(text_), parent(par)
{
}

const char* submenu::get_text(){
    return text;
}

And when you compile command.cpp, the compiler will see the following code after preprocessor substitutions:
...

class command ... {
public:
    ...
    const char* get_text();
};

...

const char* command::get_text(){
    return ...;
}


This is perfect thank you!

Glad it helps. Now please read What should I do when someone answers my question?

will do! I'm getting a compilation error, when I include lcdmenu.cpp into the add_executable() in my cmake file I get a multiple definition error but when I remove it from the function I receive a undefined reference error.
(also I do not have enough reputation to upvote, sorry)

Then you likely didn't setup something correctly when you did the separation. But that should be posted as a new question with a [mcve].
